# Sample GWT app StockWatcher works fine in Chrome and FF in dev mode but only in Firefox after compilation

Tags: java, gwt

I am new to Google Web Toolkit. I followed the tutorial given on http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted.html and built the example StockWatcher application.

**In development mode it works fine in both Firefox and Chrome**.But then i compiled the app using ant build and opened war/StockWatcher.html in Chrome. None of the dynamic elements like the main panel and add panel appeared. All i could see were the google logo and StockWatcher header text.

However, war/StockWatcher.html worked fine in Firefox. I have Firefox 7.0.1 and Google Chrome 16.0.912.77 installed on Ubuntu 11.10 and i have the gwt plugin installed in both browsers.

How can i fix this problem ?

Please Help
Thank You.

Comment: set the permutation in your module.gwt.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you simply open the file on file system? Then it is totally normal for Chrome, since it has  some serious security restrictions for using JS on local files. Deploy GWT app on some webserver, and it will be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the `user.agent` property in the `yourModule.gwt.xml` to `safari`:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari, gecko1_8" />
```

(gecko1_8 is for Firefox)

[Why safari?](http://code.google.com/p/imogene/issues/detail?id=12)